# How to select contact from section "Siri found in apps"?

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactviewcontroller, cncontactpicker

I'm using CNContactPickerViewController with properties for phone number selection:

```
picker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
picker.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count > 0")
picker.predicateForSelectionOfContact = NSPredicate(format: "phoneNumbers.@count == 1")
picker.predicateForSelectionOfProperty = NSPredicate(format: "key == phoneNumber")
```

[image: Contact with section "Siri found in apps"]

But it unable to select contact form "Siri found in apps" section. How can I enable that?

[image: Siri contact with phone number]